# Taking over GitLab administration

Tags: gitlab

Our GitLab admin (and a couple of devs) left the company recently and I have been trying to take over. How do I go about getting admin rights? I might already have them, but I'm not sure. I can ssh to our internal GitLab server, and have sudo rights. We use LDAP.

I am looking to take over a project (I am currently a developer), how would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try restoring their password

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_root_password.html

Comment: I will look at that. It may be worth nothing that we use LDAP.